# Enviar datos sin quemar a SCRAPY

Tags: scrapy

Me explico tengo listo para extraer el detalle pero recién caigo en que estoy quemando para extraer los datos.
Lo que quiero es enviar un HTML **si todo**. Pongamos el propio ejemplo de SCRAPY [quotesbot](https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot) envian un URL. lo que quiero es ENVIAR EL HTML puro. Como lo hago??

Otra cosa es como enviar una URL en su documentacion la ponen quemada pero no encuentro como enviar una??

```
start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
]
```

P.D: al decir sin quemar me refiera que no sean parte del código sino que sean el resultado de una selección o tipo "pregunta cual HTML quiere ver?" Quotes "A"

Comment: Hola Cristian ¿A que te refieres con "quemada" O "quemar"? No lo entiendo.

Comment: en lugar de poner 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/' un metodo que reciba el HTML y otra para la URL algo como. que autor quieres ver 
http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/  
http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/
...
y asi claro se envia desde otro metodo el HTML y las URL estan en un array y se envia 1x1 a la funcion respectiva

Comment: toco usar BeautifulSoup alguien creo que lo menciono pero ya no esta su comentario, sin embargo pueden tener algunos conflictos como yo pueden revisar posible problemas  [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360527/como-puedo-extraer-el-texto-y-listas-con-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si lo que quieres es descargar el HTML puedes hacer esto:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {
       "Html" : response.body
    }
```