# Como puedo extraer el texto y listas con BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

### Hoy empiezo con BeautifulSoup estaba usando usando **SCRAPY** para extraer los datos de [OER](https://www.oercommons.org/courses/randomized-synthesis-project) pero tengo 3 problemas con:

1. La **cantidad** de: visitas, veces guardados.. porque usaba **xpath** algo como **/dl[2]/dd[2]/**

- con scrapy

  `cant_visitas = response.xpath("////i[@class='fa fa-eye']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()").extract_first()`
- con **BeautifulSoup** no puedo extraer el valor (alguien sabe si **es posible** usar un **tag con espacios**)

  `cant_guardados = soup.find('li', {'id':'Number of saves'})#.find('span').get_text()`

2. Y las listas como es el caso de los grados **.getall()** (con retorno TIPO JSON) en BeautifulSoup parece que es **find_all** solo que no se como hacer lo porque usando xpath "todo es anidado dl[2]/dd[3]"

- con scrapy

  `grados = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="material-details"]/dl[2]/dd[3]/text())').getall()`
- con **BeautifulSoup**

  `grados = soup.find('div', 'material-details').select('dl:nth-of-type(2) > dd:nth-of-type(3)')`

3. Como podría extraer el valor de promedio de la valoracion, puesto que se encuentra como atributo del div

```py
cant_estrellas = soup.find('div', 'item-rating').find('div', 'stars').find_all('i', 'active-star') #div data-rating-value
cant_estrellas = len(cant_estrellas)
```

Esto trae el numero de estrellas activas no su valoracion real

P.D: creo que lo mas parecido a xpath en **BeautifulSoup** es el select pero lo mas seguro es que me equivoque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a proponer una solución utilizando `requests` y `BeautifulSoup` en la que voy a sugerir utilizar `diccionarios` o `listas`:

Hacemos la petición correspondiente a la url solicitada

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.oercommons.org/courses/randomized-synthesis-project'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,'html.parser')
```

## 1) La cantidad de visitas, veces guardados

Definimos un diccionario en el que vamos a guardar el resultado de cada item.
`counter_items` es una lista de etiquetas y cadenas de caracteres (un objeto `ResultSet`), que es el resultado de llamar al método `find_all()`.
Para acceder al valor de cada atributo de un elemento, en este caso "`title`", se utiliza `.get()`.

```
counter_items = soup.find_all(class_='counter-item')
result = dict()
for item in counter_items:
    titulo = item.get('title')
    valor = item.span.text
    result[titulo] = valor
```

Para acceder a un valor particular puedes hacer `print(result['Number of visits'])` ==> `'62'`

Su respectiva salida:

```
>>{'Number of visits': '62', 'Number of saves': '3', 'Number of comments': '0'}
```

## 2) Para la descripción

Esta es la parte más engorrosa, ya que lo que hice, fue intentar estructurar un poco los resultados. Con ayuda de una `list comprehension`, obtenemos todos los elementos `dt` de la clase `materials-details-first-part`, `strip()` y `replace` son metodos para limpiar un poco los datos, `.text` es una propiedad de `BeautifulSoup` que devuelve el texto. *por ejemplo `<a href='#foo.com'> texto del link</a>` (si en ese elemento usamos `.text` , nos devuelve 'texto del link')*

Como la descripción esta dividida en dos párrafos, tenemos que unir los dos resultados en una lista sola. 
Por un lado los títulos `(dts+dts_segunda)`, y por otro lado el contenido`(dds+dds_segunda)` de cada título

```
dts = [i.text.strip().replace(':','') for i in soup.find_all(class_='materials-details-first-part')[0].find_all('dt')]
dds = [i.text.strip().replace('\n','') for i in soup.find_all(class_='materials-details-first-part')[0].find_all('dd')]

dts_segunda = [i.text.strip().replace(':','') for i in soup.find_all(class_='material-details-second-part')[0].find_all('dt')]
dds_segunda = [i.text.strip().replace('\n','') for i in soup.find_all(class_='material-details-second-part')[0].find_all('dd')]

result_dts = dts+dts_segunda
result_dds = dds+dds_segunda
```

Ahora definimos un diccionario para guardar la descripción completa. Con ayuda de la función [zip()](https://micro.recursospython.com/recursos/la-funcion-zip.html), obtenemos un diccionario donde cada clave tiene su valor correspondiente.

```
materials_details = dict()
for dt,dd in zip(result_dts,result_dds):
    materials_details[dt]=dd
```

Si quieres saber por ejemplo el Level, `print(materials_details['Level']) >>'Computer Science'`

Salida:

```
{'Subject': 'Computer Science',
 'Level': 'Lower Primary',
 'Grades': 'Kindergarten, Grade 1, Grade 2',
 'Material Type': 'Activity/Lab, Lesson',
 'Author': 'Boot up PD',
 'Provider': 'Boot Up PD',
 'Date Added': '09/23/2019',
 'License': 'Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 4.0',
 'Language': 'English',
 'Media Format': 'Downloadable docs, Text/HTML'}
```

## 3) Promedio de valoración:

Bueno esta es la parte más sencilla ya que solo se obtiene de la siguiente manera:
`.find` devuelve un **(1) solo elemento**. a diferencia de `.find_all`. Como queremos el valor del atributo `'data-raiting-value'`, se lo pedimos con `.get()`. y con eso tendríamos lo que necesitabamos.

```
raiting = soup.find(class_='stars').get('data-rating-value')

print(raiting) >> 0.0
```

pd: Si no te gusta trabajar con diccionarios o simplemente no te sientes cómodo, puedes definir una lista, y para guardar los datos como "fila" dentro de la misma. ej:

```
counter_items = soup.find_all(class_='counter-item')
result = []
for item in counter_items:
    titulo = item.get('title')
    valor = item.span.text
    result.append([titulo,valor])

result[0] --> ['Number of visits', '62']
```

Espero que haya podido resolver tus dudas

Comment: vaya yo lo esta haciendo asi
 `cant_comentarios = soup.find('li', {'title':'Number of comments'}).span.string`
o usando la propiedad
 `visión_general = soup.find('div', 'material-details').find('dl','materials-details-abstract').find('dd', {'itemprop':'description'}).get_text()` gracias